# Will F# type providers provide a good base for implementing an object-relational mapping?

Tags: orm, f#, type-providers

Judging from the information I have read about type providers so far, I wonder if they could be used to implement a nice ORM for F#.

I imagine that database rows could be represented by objects with correctly-typed properties, allowing type-safe read and write access to column values, with the type provider implementation automatically checking against the current database schema when compiling.

Is this a realistic and useful scenario?

Comment: +1 Good question. Still awaiting a technology to simplify and improve ORMs. Maybe type providers will help?

Comment: @Daniel - have you ever used Linq-to-Sql? I think it's brilliant (well, the C# implementation at least, the F# implementation doesn't appear to be ready for prime-time). I dislike the Entity framework / Hibernate heavy-duty variety of ORMS: I think the relational model is well-merited as a flexible, efficient, queryable storage model, and I can't understand the desire to prematurely abstract away its power through up-front object mappings (beyond 1-to-1 table mappings for further ad-hoc querying). The pain, I feel, is in RDBMS implementations and SQL, and Linq-to-Sql heals much of that.

Comment: @Stephen: Most ORMs provide (presumably because most developers want) static representations of their data. I'd rather have dynamicity (e.g., if I add a column, the ORM should "pick it up"; I shouldn't have to re-gen code). Because of this, I haven't spent much time with Linq-to-Sql. It seems it would be trivial to achieve the syntactic behavior I want using something like `System.Dynamic.DynamicObject`, but that leaves the more complicated part to deal with: RDBMS implementation details.

Comment: @Stephen: (cont.) I like this question because type providers seem to provide dynamicity and type safety, and would therefore (in my mind) be a perfect tool for implementing an ORM.

Comment: At least one of the type providers available on NuGet today - Jan 2017 - picks up the schema live from the DB. I myself prefer static generation through SqlMetal for Linq2Sql, because I don't want the build to depend on a live DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's an interesting use of type providers. One of the examples does just that, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361033(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct then Type providers will be sort of "plugins" to F# compiler. They will plug the type information that F# compiler is not able to find while compiling the code. So basically while compiling the F# code the compiler will ask the type providers to fill in the types information which is not know to F# compiler. This also does mean that it is still about static typing i.e types are identified at compile time.

If the above understanding is correct, then in case of an ORM, you will need to implement a type provider for your relational scheme and this type provider will be used by F# compiler to compile your code to "fill-in" the types which represents your ORM mappings.

If you look at ORM, they are not just about mapping relational data to Objects, but also provide various operations like query, update etc on underlying relational data. In my opinion I don't think at this moment F# type providers are good for ORM, but I may be wrong :)

Comment: Yes, I understand that type providers will not provide the actual functionality of an ORM. But I'm wondering if they would be useful to make an ORM statically type-safe, without using code generation.

Comment: But you do get type safety with ORM generated code as well .. isn't it?